# How to find branch points for complex functions?

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-numbers

I'm looking for a standard way I can approach problems where I am tasked to find the branch points and branch cuts of a complex function.

For instance,

$$ f(z) = e^{(z^2+1)^{1/2}}$$

or

$$ f(z) = \log(z^2-3)$$

My current understanding is that you relate a more complicated function to what you know.

For example,

$$ (z-i)^{1/3}$$

where we let $z'=z-i$, and we have $z'^{1/3}$ whose branch points we know are $0$ and $\infty$. Hence, using $z'=z-i$, we see that the branch points are $i$ and $\infty$.

But I'm unsure if there is a more fundamental way to go about this - any advice?

Comment: Do you know the definition of a branch point? What have you been taught about it?

Comment: I do. If you travel a small circuit around a branch point to the point you started from, you will have two different values associated with one point (multivalued function).

Comment: The key thing to note there is that this is not possible if the function is analytic at the branch point, or even has a pole. So to find branch points you look for essential singularities.

Comment: So you're saying if a function is analytic it is by definition single-valued? So by searching for points where analyticity fails I can find branch point candidates?